# Изменение id согласно номеру

Tags: jquery

Есть несколько братских элементов выглядящих так:

```
<div id="list" class="lst">
...
</div>
```

Как можно с помощью jquery изменить его id, согласно порядковому номеру? Например у первого элемента, сменить id на "list_1", у второго на "list_2" и тд. Подскажите как лучше реализовать?

***Update***

Вот что у меня получилось, все прекрасно работает, но может есть вариант проще?

```
$("#build_calculator").find(".lst").each(function() {
if ($(this).attr('id') == 'list') {
$(this).attr('id','list_' + ($(this).index('.lst') + 1));
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и без jQuery:

```
var lst = [];
lst = document.querySelectorAll("#list.lst");
for (i = 0; i < lst.length; ++i) {
    lst[i].id += i + 1;
}
```

А можно и с jQuery:

```
$("#list.lst").each(function (i) {
    this.id += i + 1;
});
```

Comment: Уверены, что будут выбраны все элементы с одинаковым айдишником?

Comment: Прежде, чем написать ответ, я все проверил. Смотрите сами: http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/UmNML/

Comment: Хм, оба способа работают и в мозилле и в хроме. Тоже проверил.

Comment: В Опере тоже работает. И в IE. Если версию библиотеки jQuery выбрать пониже, тут я ступил.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#build_calculator .lst").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'list') {
        $(this).attr('id', 'list_' + index);
    }
});
```

Comment: Думаю, что ТС нужно, чтоб начиналось с единицы.

    $(this).attr('id', 'list_' + index + 1);

@HappyCougar, вообще, что-то не правильно. Получается, что изначально у вас на странице множество элементов с одинаковым ID. Может использовать какой-нибудь дополнительный класс?